# how to serialize map with struct

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm trying to boost serialize a map value with struct as key, but i'm getting below error while compiling my code:

```
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:116:11: error: ‘struct main(int, char**)::MyKey’ has no member named ‘serialize’
         t.serialize(ar, file_version);
```

Here is the main code which i'm using:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init (argc, argv, "training");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    struct MyKey {
        int d0, d1, d2, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2;

        bool operator < (const MyKey& o) const {
        return std::tie(d0, d1, d2, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2) < std::tie(o.d0, o.d1, o.d2, o.a0, o.b0, o.a1, o.b1, o.a2, o.b2);
        }
    };

    struct MyValue {
        int p0, p1, p2;
    };

    std::map<MyKey, MyValue> pobj;

    std::ofstream s("obj_pattern"); boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(s);
    for(int i=0;i<5000000;i++) {
        pobj.insert({{i, i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4, i+5, i+6, i+7, i+8}, {i+9, i+10, i+11}});
        oa << pobj;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How do i remove this error?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serialize user-defined types you need to add *serialize* function template into your class. In this method you state what data members of your class are serialized/restored.

Because member function template cannot be defined for local class move definitions of *MyKey*, *MyValue* out of *main* function:

```
    struct MyKey {
        int d0, d1, d2, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2;

        bool operator < (const MyKey& o) const {
        return std::tie(d0, d1, d2, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2) 
                   < std::tie(o.d0, o.d1, o.d2, o.a0, o.b0, o.a1, o.b1, o.a2, o.b2);
        }

        template<class Ar>
        void serialize (Ar& ar, const unsigned int) {
            ar & d0;
            ar & d1;
            // ditto 
        }
    };

    struct MyValue {
        int p0, p1, p2;

        template<class Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar, const unsigned int) {
            ar & p0;
            ar & p1;
            //
        }
    };


int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  //...
}
```

You should call `oa << pobj;` only once, after you built the map:

```
    for(int i=0;i<5000000;i++) {
        pobj.insert({{i, i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4, i+5, i+6, i+7, i+8}, {i+9, i+10, i+11}});
    }
    oa << pobj;
```

Comment: @DineshLama You need to define input stream, create `boost::archive::text_iarchive` and call opertor >> on this object: `std::map<MyKey, MyValue> pobj; std::ifstream s("obj_pattern"); boost::archive::text_iarchive oa(s); oa >> pobj;`. If you are writing/reading in the same program, ensure that output stream is closed before reading operations are performed.

Comment: actually i wanted to read those values using memory mapping i was trying to use boost serialization but getting problems.